# Using a subclass object as a parameter in a class inheriting from an abstract class

Tags: c++, class, virtual-functions

I'm creating two classes. The first is an abstract base class, and the second inherits from the first.

```
struct Animal
{
    bool is_multicellular;
    int children;
    Animal() {
        this->is_multicellular = true;
        this->children = 0;
    }
    
    virtual Animal& attempt_to_mate(Animal&) = 0;
};

struct Bear : Animal
{
    bool has_fur;
    bool wants_to_mate;
    Bear() : Animal() {
        this->has_fur = true;
    }
    
    
    Animal& attempt_to_mate(Animal &bear) override {
        bear = dynamic_cast<Bear&>(bear);
        if (bear.wants_to_mate) {
            this->children ++;
        }
        return bear;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bear bear1;
    bear1.wants_to_mate = true;
    Bear bear2;
    bear2.attempt_to_mate(bear1);
}
```

When I compile, the compiler tells me

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘virtual Animal& Bear::attempt_to_mate(Animal&)’:
main.cpp:32:18: error: ‘struct Animal’ has no member named ‘wants_to_mate’; did you mean ‘attempt_to_mate’?
         if (bear.wants_to_mate) {
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

While Animal does not have the variable `wants_to_mate`, Bear does, and I'm trying to cast the animal to bear. One way of fixing my issue is to move the variable `wants_to_mate` to the Animal class. Is there a way I could fix my issue while keeping the variable in the Bear class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the cast wrong.

```
Animal& attempt_to_mate(Animal &bear) override {
    bear = dynamic_cast<Bear&>(bear);
    if (bear.wants_to_mate) {
        this->children ++;
    }
    return bear;
}
```

`bear` is reference to an animal. You can assign a reference to a `Bear` to it, but that wont turn it into a reference to a bear. Just like assigning a `double` to an `int` does not magically turn the `int` into a `double`:

```
 int x = 5;
 x = static_cast<double>(x) + 0.5;
 std::cout << x;  // x is still 5
```

Instead declare a reference to a `Bear` and use that:

```
Animal& attempt_to_mate(Animal &bear) override {
    Bear& b = dynamic_cast<Bear&>(bear);
    if (b.wants_to_mate) {
        this->children ++;
    }
    return bear;
}
```

Comment: Addendum: If you call `attempt_to_mate` with an `Animal` that is not a `Bear`, the `dynamic_cast` will fail and throw `std::bad_cast`. So much for Bear/Chicken hybrids.